# FULL TEXT only select if at least X words match

Tags: mysql, sql, string, full-text-search, where-clause

```
SELECT source, id
FROM  memory_row
WHERE memory_id =10

AND MATCH(source) 
AGAINST ('girl*, appears*,  cool*, pragmatic*,  things*,  first*,  glance*,  actually*,  warm*,
 trusting*, created*,  Design*,  Children*,  Togetsu*,  existed*,  solely*,  activate*,  Strings*,  
experienced*,  emotional*,  damage*,  young*,  from*,  experiments*,  conducted*, her*,  cruel*,  
researchers*,  sent*,  Randall*,  family*,  treatment*,  after*,  sealing*,  memories*, small*,  world*,
  older*,  adoptive*,  sister*,  Naomi*')
```

The above query returns results in which only a few words match. I want to only return results that contain at least X of the terms that are being matched against. In the example above, that number can be 10. That means that the column must contain at least 10 fulltext matches to be returned.

How can I do this?

**EDIT**
One answer suggested the following. I get an error, "Incorrect arguments to AGAINST".

```
select m.*
from memory_row m
where 
    memory_id = 10
    and (
        select count(*)
        from (
            select 'girl*' word
            union all select 'appears*'
            union all select 'actually*'
            union all select 'girl*'
            union all select 'cool*'
            union all select 'pragmatic*'
            union all select 'things*'
            union all select 'first*'
            union all select 'glance*'
            union all select 'actually*'
        ) w
        where match(m.source) against(w.word)
    ) >= 5
```

Answer (score 3):

I am unsure that there is an easy way to do what you want. You might need to enumerate the values as rows, and then use a correlated subquery to compute the count of matches:

```
select m.*
from memory_row m
where 
    memory_id = 10
    and (
        select count(*)
        from (
            select 'girl*' word
            union all select 'appears*'
            ...
        ) w
        where match(m.source) against(w.word)
    ) >= ?
```

Where the qestion mark represents the minimum number of rows that should match.

Or, in very recent versions of MySQL:

```
select m.*
from memory_row m
    where 
    memory_id = 10
    and (
        select count(*)
        from (values row('girl*'), row('appears*'), ...) w(word)
        where match(m.source) against(w.word)
    ) >= ?
```

Comment: I get an error. "Incorrect arguments to AGAINST. I'l edit my post with query attempt.

Answer (score 2):

One method is to use `match` to get an initial set of documents.  And then additional logic afterwards:

```
SELECT mr.*
FROM (SELECT source, id
      FROM memory_row
      WHERE memory_id = 10 AND
            MATCH(source) AGAINST ('girl*, appears*,  cool*, pragmatic*,  things*,  first*,  glance*,  actually*,  warm*,
 trusting*, created*,  Design*,  Children*,  Togetsu*,  existed*,  solely*,  activate*,  Strings*,  
experienced*,  emotional*,  damage*,  young*,  from*,  experiments*,  conducted*, her*,  cruel*,  
researchers*,  sent*,  Randall*,  family*,  treatment*,  after*,  sealing*,  memories*, small*,  world*,
  older*,  adoptive*,  sister*,  Naomi*')
     ) mr
WHERE ( (source like '%girl%') +
        (source like '%actually%') +
        . . .
      ) >= 10;
```

Note:  This is not *exactly* the same logic, because it is just looking for strings.  If you want more precise logic, you can use regular expressions, but that might not be necessary.

Comment: As far as efficiency is concerned, how does this compare to the other answer given by GMB? Also, isn't the first % sign unnecessary as I only care about what proceeds the word?

Comment: @FrogGuacamole . . . The `%` is necessary because you are looking for a string in the middle of a string.  As to which is better, you'll have to try yourself.  It might depend on how long `source` is and on how many words you are looking for.